# JavaScript createElement Line Causes Error

Tags: javascript, html, dom, createelement

I'm writing a simple JavaScript program to examine every element in an HTML website and add a child node to every non-text node that labels the type of tag:

[image: browser screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var body_elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < body_elems.length; i++) {
        if (body_elems[i].nodeType != 3) {
            var tag_name = body_elems[i].tagName;
            var child = document.createElement("P");
            var child_text = document.createTextNode(tag_name);
            child.appendChild(child_text);
            body_elems[i].appendChild(child);
            body_elems[i].firstChild.className = "hoverNode";
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the line `var child = document.createElement("P")` causes the page to never load; if I comment out that line then the page will load.

On the other hand, here is a slightly different version that actually works:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var body_elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < body_elems.length; i++) {
        if (body_elems[i].nodeType != 3) {
            var tag_name = body_elems[i].tagName;
            var child = document.createTextNode(tag_name);
            body_elems[i].appendChild(child);
            child.className="hoverNode";
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to assign a class name to the new node in order to apply CSS, so if someone could tell me how to do that my problem would be solved.

I'm new to JS so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think document.createElement("p"); would work (lowercase).

Comment: Is an error logged? Note that there are some tags (like `<img>` or `<br>`) that can't have any child nodes.

Comment: @Feathercrown that doesn't work.

Comment: @pointy I can't find any error, I can only get the page to load if I first load it with that line commented out, then set a breakpoint before that, then un-comment it and reload. Then if I traverse through I still can't find an error.

Comment: If there is at least one node in the document which is not a TextNode then the first script will run forever as `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live collection hence `body_elems` will also contain the newly created `p` elements.

Comment: @Andreas good call, thanks. I think I can fix it based on that.

Comment: Use [`document.querySelectorAll("*")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead. This will return a non-live NodeList.

Comment: @Andreas Good catch! Add your answer so that we can cast some votes :)

Comment: You can not just append `p` elements to every element. You will be generating invalid markup since a `p` can not be a sibling of inputs, images, lists, tbody, etc.

Comment: @epascarello I changed it to `span` elements, and the only reason I'm doing this is for an assignment that requires it to be done this way.

Comment: A span can not be inside certain elements also... You would need to append it after an element.

Comment: @epascarello well it worked so I'm happy

Comment: @possum_pendulum Welp, I tried.